# Java & LibGDX: Limit Rendering Range of a Sprite

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, render

Recently I switched from using an `array` of integers as my screen in Java to using a library. The library I'm using is `LibGDX`, and the conversion for me is quite different. Most things I have already started to get the hang of, and I'm still writing a bit of the code myself.

At this point, I'm curious if I can limit the rendering range of `Sprite`s and any other factor of drawing, such as if a sprite stuck half-way out of a box, it wouldn't render the part that was sticking out (as so:)

[image: Example of Rendering in a Range]

Is there a way to render in a specific range, and if it is partially out of the range, it doesn't render what is out of the range, or will I have to do that myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do simple "clipping" to a rectangle with the [LibGDX ScissorStack](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Clipping%2C-with-the-use-of-scissorstack).

Because OpenGL is stateful and many of the LibGDX drawing APIs cache, be sure to "flush" or "end" your batches within the range of the scissors.  See [libgdx ScissorStack not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889828/libgdx-scissorstack-not-working-as-expected) and [libgdx Cutting an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275914/libgdx-cutting-an-image?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If i did not missunderstand you, you are looking for `camera`.
The `camera` lets you define a `Viewport` (size) and you only see things inside this `Viewport`.
You can also move it arroung to see other parts of the world.

For example:

```
OrthographicCamera cam = new OrthographicCamera(80, 45);
```

This defines a `camera`, which showes you 80 units in x and 45 units in y. It P(0/0) by default is in the middle of the screen, so this `camera` shows objects from -40 to +40 in x and -22.5 to + 22.5 in y.
You can move it, so that the P(0/0) is in the left lower corner:

```
camera.position.x = -40;
camera.position.y = -22.5;
camera.update();
```

This should move the camera to the left by 40 units and down by 22.5 units, so that the P(0/0) is the left lower corner. Don't forget to call `update()` as this recalculates the projection and view matrix.

Finally, to draw with this `camera`, you need to set the `SptieBatch`s `projectionMatrix` to the one of the `camera`:

```
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
```

Now you can use this `SpriteBatch` to draw.
You should also consider to se `ViewFrustum-Culling`, which means, that you don't draw things out of the `camera`, because they will never appear on screen, but the draw call costs some performance.